# Is there any good software for Linux for FM radio listening?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet-radio

I have a Asus tv card containing of Philips chip set. I'm using this card with Cyberlink Power Cinema in windows OS.

Is there any good soft ware for Linux similar to the Cyberlink Power Cinema? I'm only using this card for listen to the FM radio.So any good radio card handling software ?

Comment: Why use FM Radio?even you are a sri lankan, there are some good Internet radios in the Internet that u can find interesting.

Comment: Yap that,s true bro.But the problem is my net connection speed.After i exceed the bandwidth limit my service provider drop the connection speed.

Comment: I agree,sometimes it takes about 50mb for 15minutees!(depending on some reasons)

Answer (score 3):

**Rhythmbox** has an *FM Radio* plugin that lets you configure radio stations and tune in to them the same way you'd pick other media.  You can enable it from `Edit` -> `Plugins`, and then add new presets with `Music` -> `New FM Radio Station`.

It depends on proper `video4linux` drivers for the tuner hardware, and expects that the card will handle getting audio to the speakers.  I've used it successfully with a tuner that connected through to the line in jack of the sound card.  It was necessary to turn on unmute that input with `alsamixer -c0` so that the audio passed through to the speakers, but other than that it worked fine.

If your tuner card handles audio in some other way (e.g. it doesn't have a direct connection to the sound card, and instead shows up as a separate sound device), it might not work out of the box though.

Answer (score 1):

**[Gnomeradio](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnomeradio/)** is a FM radio tuner for the GNOME desktop. It should work with every FM tuner card that is supported by video4linux. Remote controls are supported via (optional) LIRC support. Gnomeradio can also record radio using GStreamer backend.

Answer (score 0):

Does your hardware listed in Ubuntu Hardware compatible list in [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFriendly) if it is yes there should be drivers for it, If it is not, try your hardware vendors web site, browse and find the drivers for Ubuntu-linux, and carefully read instructions and install it (Some media center apps supports those hardware)

Comment: I think I found the answer, Try searching tv card or fm radio in the synaptic and install what fits you by reading the description, It works for me anyway for my cheap gadmei Tv card, Comment me if it does not

Answer (score -1):

```
# fmradio.sh
# para no confundir con el paquete radio, y modificar estaciones.

: ${DIALOG=dialog}
: ${DIALOG_SINTONIZAR=0}
: ${DIALOG_APAGAR=1}
: ${DIALOG_HELP=2}
: ${DIALOG_EXTRA=3}
: ${DIALOG_ITEM_HELP=4}
: ${DIALOG_ESC=255}

tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null` || tempfile=/tmp/test$$
trap "rm -f $tempfile" 0 1 2 5 15


$DIALOG --clear --title "SINTONIZADOR DE RADIO FM PERONISTA" "$@" \
        --menu "Elija una emisora:" 20 50 17 \
        "1" "87.9 Radio UBA" \
        "2" "88.3 FM Latinos" \
        "3" "88.5" \
        "4" "89.1 FM Malena" \
        "5"  "89.3 Radio Gráfica" \
        "6"  "89.6" \
        "7"  "89.9 Radio con Vos" \
        "8"  "90.3 FM Delta" \
        "9"  "91.1 Radio Si" \
        "10"  "91.5 Radio Sol" \
        "11"  "92.1 Radio Red" \
        "12"  "92.6" \
        "13"  "92.9" \
        "14" "93.3 FM BitBox" \
        "15" "93.7" \
        "16" "93.9 Radio Palermo" \
        "17" "94.3 Radio Disney" \
        "18" "95.1 Metro" \
        "19" "95.5 FM Concepto" \
        "20" "95.9 FM Rock & Pop" \
        "21" "96.3 Radio Ciudades" \
        "22" "96.7 Nacional Clásica" \
        "23" "97.1 Radio Provincia" \
        "24" "97.5 Vale FM" \
        "25" "97.8 Retro FM" \
        "26" "98.3 Mega FM" \
        "27" "98.7 Nacional Folklórica" \
        "28" "99.1 Cadena 3" \
        "29" "99.9 La Cien" \
        "30" "100.3 La Colifata" \
        "31" "100.7 Radio Blue" \
        "32" "101.1 Radio Latina FM" \
        "33" "101.5 Radio POP" \
        "34" "102.3 FM Aspen" \
        "35" "103.6" \
        "36" "103.7" \
        "37" "103.8 FM OndaSur" \
        "38" "104.3 RQP LRL322" \
        "39" "105.5 FM Hit" \
    "40" "106.2" \
        "41" "106.7 FM Millenium" \
    "42" "107.5" 2> $tempfile

retval=$?

case $retval in
$DIALOG_SINTONIZAR)
clear


echo Sintonizando la emisora elegida...
echo De no reproducir active el canal Loopback en Alsamixer
echo y elija otra emisora o seleccione Cancel para detener la radio.

case `cat $tempfile` in
1) station='87.90';;
2) station='88.30';;
3) station='88.50';;
4) station='89.10';;
5) station='89.30';;
6) station='89.60';;
7) station='89.90';;
8) station='90.30';;
9) station='91.10';;
10) station='91.50';;
11) station='92.10';;
12) station='92.60';;
13) station='92.90';;
14) station='93.30';;
15) station='93.70';;
16) station='93.90';;
17) station='94.30';;
18) station='95.10';;
19) station='95.50';;
20) station='95.90';;
21) station='96.30';;
22) station='96.70';;
23) station='97.10';;
24) station='97.50';;
25) station='97.80';;
26) station='98.30';;
27) station='98.70';;
28) station='99.10';;
29) station='99.90';;
30) station='100.30';;
31) station='100.70';;
32) station='101.10';;
33) station='101.50';;
34) station='102.30';;
35) station='103.60';;
36) station='103.70';;
37) station='103.80';;
38) station='104.30';;
39) station='105.50';;
40) station='106.20';;
41) station='106.70';;
42) station='107.20'
esac
;;

$DIALOG_APAGAR)
     fm off
amixer set 'Loopback Mixing' Disabled
     clear
echo Cerrando Perón Radio y reproducción detenida.
     exit 0;;

esac

fm on
amixer set 'Loopback Mixing' Enabled >/dev/null
exec >/dev/null 2>&1
fm $station &!
exec >/dev/tty

exec pradio.sh
clear
```