# FM Radio without Internet?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is it possible to use FM radio WITHOUT internet connection or special devices ?

On my Android phone, I can plug in the headphones, which are in turn used as antenna.
Since Android is Linux and Ubuntu is also Linux, it should be possible to do this on a plain old Ubuntu notebook (13.04), too. Is it ? Or does it need special FM-receiver electronics ?

If yes, which application can I use for FM-Radio ?

I repeat: Live FM-Radio **WITHOUT** internet connection at the time of listening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to use FM radio WITHOUT internet connection or special devices ?

No. Best option is to get a FM-radio tuner. There are USB versions of such tuners though most are TV tuners with an added FM radio tuner.

And [gnomeradio](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gnomeradio/) is a piece of software for that:

[image]

Oh I know of 1 notebook with a 3.0 x FM antenna: Toshiba Satellite A305-S6863.

Answer (score 5):

The FM-Radio works because there is FM receiver (hardware). So you need a FM receiver first in notebook. Most of notebooks doesn't come with FM receiver.

It is just not the software part.

You can get a USB FM receiver and use it. After that can have a look here - [Is there any good software for Linux for FM radio listening?](https://askubuntu.com/q/111363/35775)

Comment: Toshiba Satellite A305-S6863 has a 3.0 x FM antenna ;)

Comment: wow.. really. Nice :)